# CSS and Recaptcha

Tags: css, recaptcha

I have implemented recaptcha in a form but there's a conflict with the CSS. I saw on firebug that the recaptcha `<tr>` inherit some properties of my tables but I am not able to change them. I just want recaptcha not to be influenced by my css.

Here's the css interfering with it. [Here](http://www.assatena.it/Atena/GENinsertUtente1.php) you can see the form

Thank you.

```
.GEN_form tr:first-child, tr:first-child td{
    background-color: #52d053; /*verde*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:24px;
    height: 50px;
}
.GEN_form tr:last-child{
    background-color: #52d053; /*verde*/
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "not" property in your css.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Comment: Hi thanks..I managed to have the top line (tr:first-child td:not(.recaptchatable recaptcha_theme_red))working but not the bottom one..plus it does not move to the center of the table (using colspan='2')